# Filter array of Firebase QueryDocumentSnapshot with three keys Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, filter, snapshot

I have applied a filter to a simple array but now data is in `QueryDocumentSnapshot` Array I am unable to filter it and it is meant to be filtered with 3 keys `phone`, `name`, `email`

```
extension CleanerListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchText.isEmpty{
             filterList = self.cleaner
        }else{
            let keys = ["name", "phone", "email"]
            let subPredicates = keys.map({ NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", $0, searchText) })
            let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)
           // cleaner is of type [QueryDocumentSnapshot]!
            filterList = cleaner.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }

        }
        self.tblCleanerList.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I have tried `.filter` with an array of `[QueryDocumentSnapshot]` but unable to figure how to do

It gives crash

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot 0x600002b00580> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

Comment: please add some input output example and your code

Comment: bro, u can check I have an updated and ```filterList``` was previous data array now it comes in ```[QueryDocumentSnapshot]``` now I want filter ```QueryDocumentSnapshot``` array

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper QueryDocumentSnapshot is a object not a variable so you set the object name start with lowerCase like queryDocumentSnapshot or try this let filteredArray = cleners.filter { $0.phone == "examplePhone" }

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot 0x600002b00580> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

Comment: @Vicaren It gives Crash